# cannot close recent apps using adb shell input keyevent

Tags: android, adb

I use the following code:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH
adb shell input keyevent 20
adb shell input keyevent DEL
```

the 1st line of code works.. it does indeed open the recent app window.. however i wanted it to press the close or X button

[image]

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do it using the following command

```
 adb shell input tap x y
```

replace x and y with the X button position on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

you may simulate swipe the screen with the following command

```
adb shell input swipe 500 500 500 1000 100
```